# Mac: Failed building wheel for xmlsec

Tags: python-3.x, onelogin, xmlsec

Attempting to spin up OneLogin's sample Flask project and getting:

```
Failed to build xmlsec
ERROR: Could not build wheels for xmlsec which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

While trying to install dependancies.  I have tried everything I have found here and elsewhere without success:

```
brew install libxml2 libxmlsec1 pkg-config

brew install libxmlsec1
```

I've tried installing it via python3-saml, tried with --no-use-pep517

Despite numerous reports, I have found no work-through to get this working.

MacBook Pro, Intel, MacOS Catalina, Python 3.8.2, pip 21.0.1 (from 3.8)

Hoping there is a clear solution to this out there somewhere.